# XFA Form conversion to PDFA-1B

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

We have a requirement to convert XFA Form (Adobe LiveCycle Form) to PDF/A-1B.
We're attempting to use iText 5.4.0 to parse the PDF, populate the XFA fields and then save the modified PDF back out.
All the examples I can find with iText talk about populating XFA fields into PDF.
Can I convert an XFA form ( static / dynamic and generated using LiveCycle) to PDFA 1b directly?
As need PDFA for sure and can’t live with plain PDFs. So as workaround we were thinking about converting the PDF to PDFA. Is that the right approach or we are missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Adobe LiveCycle Forms Server or PDF Generator for this purpose.  It supports conversion of XFA-based forms (either static or dynamic) to either PDF/A-1b or PDF/A-1a.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We did have the option of Adobe LiveCycle but enterprise strategy is to move away from LiveCycle. Hence we were exploring other avenues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert XFA forms to PDF/A using iText in combination with XFA Worker. However, XFA Worker is a closed source product. So you need to be an iText customer if you want to achieve what you want.

Note that we've done exactly what you need in a project for the Ministry of Justice in Belgium. I've written the following blog post about this project: : http://lowagie.com/xfabpm

**Disclaimer:** I'm the CEO of the iText Software Group. This answer isn't meant to promote the product. It's a genuine answer to this question.

Comment: Can you please share the licensing cost @ deepakkumar.sharma@thrivent.com?

Comment: That would be out of scope here. Also: the price would depend on the use: server/desktop, perpetual/subscription,... There are other places to discuss this; I've forwarded this request to the appropriate people.

Comment: Ok thanks. As I mentioned, please share the relevant details at my business email deepakkumar.sharma@thrivent.com

Answer (score -1):

I was also looking for the same problem and I reached an easy solution, you can try this out:

1. Drag and drop it xfa format PDF into chrome, it will open in chrome browser.
2. You will find three options at right corner:

   - Rotate clockwise
   - Download
   - Print
3. Click on "Print"
4. Change destination "save as PDF" and save.

Saved PDF is flat PDF(Acroform) and can be edited easily